# Invalid version control suffix in bitbucket.org/ path when importing private repo in golang

Tags: go, bitbucket, importerror

The steps I took:

1- Configure .gitconfig

```
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/"]
    insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

2- export GOPRIVATE=bitbucket.org/myproject/helpers-go

3- go get

my go.mod file ->

```
module bitbucket.org/myproject/x/test-service

go 1.16

require (
    bitbucket.org/myproject/helpers-go v0.0.2
)

replace bitbucket.org/myproject/helpers-go => bitbucket.org/myproject/helpers-go.git v0.0.2
```

- My ssh key works. I can push/pull each services.
- I also have the v0.0.2 tag on my last helpers-go commit.

I am trying to import private repo(helpers-go) into (test-service) and the error I get is :

```
go: bitbucket.org/myproject/helpers-go@v0.0.2: invalid version control suffix in bitbucket.org/ path
```

Even if I change the v0.0.2 to something random like v0.0.9 which I don`t have a tag like this, I still get the same error.
Appreciate the help...

Answer (score 1):

it is solved:

1- I was using go 1.16 and there was an issue with bitbucket private repos not being supported for this version. I don`t think it has the same issue with gitlab. Upgrading it to go 1.19

2- Small change here **.org/ -> .org:**

```
[url "git@bitbucket.org:"]
        insteadOf = https://bitbucket.org/
```

3- Also making sure the private repo I am importing has a file that ends with **.go**. My .go files were all in other folders leaving main folder without a **.go** file.